# React: CORS error when API 302 redirects to same domain

Tags: reactjs, axios, cors

I have a React web app (`a.com`) that communicates with an API (`b.api`) via axios/XHR requests.

Now there is a specific request that the server answers with a 302 redirect to another `a.com` location. This fails with a CORS error in Chrome:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://a.com/redirectpath' (redirected from 'https://b.api/requestpath') from origin 'https://a.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Contrary to the error message, the preflight request of the triggered redirect seems to have `origin: null` set. Is this the problem? Why does this happen, if the redirect goes to the same domain the user is on (`a.com`)?

Thank you for any ides!

Comment: An `Authorization` header necessitates a preflight request, does this come back with `Authorization` an allowed header (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71989582/16462950))?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Ouch, I confused myself here: The redirect location (a.com URL) itself doesn't need Authorization, only a subsequent request to the API would. I removed the misleading paragraph from my question. Sorry...

Comment: Looks like a request to the same origin is still considered cross-origin if it is triggered by a redirect from a different origin. And the preflight is then indeed made with `Origin: null`. But what causes the preflight in your case, if it is not the `Authorization` header?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Ah! So you are saying the 302 redirect could well be a "simple request" without preflight, were it not for certain conditions. But what could those be? I would say offending headers, but where would I look for those in the case of a redirect? In the 302 response headers? The preflight request headers do include `access-control-request-headers: authorization` - does this matter? Also the site is behind Basic Auth for what it's worth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I understood, this is what happened:

- Browser makes a cross-origin request with `Authorization` header to `b.api`.
- The `Authorization` header necessitates a preflight request, which is successful.
- The response from `b.api` is a 302 redirect to `a.com`.
- The browser makes the redirected request to `a.com`, which includes the same `Authorization` header again.
- Although this request goes to the same origin, it is still considered cross-origin because it was triggered by a redirect from a different origin. (See also the difference between "HTTP-redirect fetch" and "scheme fetch" explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75184259/samesite-strict-cookies-and-cross-site-requests-with-redirections).)
- The `Authorization` header therefore necessitates a preflight request to `a.com`, with `Origin: null`.
- This second preflight request is unsuccessful: `a.com` does not return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` (nor `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization`).

I think the problem is the behavior of `b.api`: A cross-origin-enabled request that requires an `Authorization` header should *not* lead to a 302 response, because that carries over the `Authorization` header (and with it the credential!) to a *different* server.

More fundamentally, requests that contain credentials in an `Authorization` header are typically made by a *server* that is able to keep the credentials secret, not by a *react app* where the credentials are vulnerable to cross-site scripting attacks. For server-to-server requests, CORS is not involved at all. But `b.api` seems not to share this view, otherwise it would not need to cross-site-enable such requests.

Comment: Thank you for your assessment, which sounds entirely plausible, event though I admit I'm a little out of my depths here. You write, '_The browser makes the redirected request to a.com, which includes the same Authorization header (and credentials?) again._' - that means that any authorized API request that returns a 302 redirect would by definition include the entire 'Bearer ...' Authorization header in the redirected request (if CORS wouldn't forbid it)?

Comment: Yes, the credentials are carried over to the new endpoint, unless they are kept in a cookie.

Comment: I see! We decided to commission an API change instead of hacking our way around this horrible behaviour. Thank you for walking me through this!

Comment: Hello, We are this problem today with our React App. In our case the server is salesforce so b.api is responding with 302 with location header and it cannot be changed or configured.

The browser is sending Options and it is failing because the server which is in PHP deployed on IIS , does not respond with Access-Control-Allowed-Headers.

Is there any other way to overcome this issue ?