# Laravel 5.5 CORS issue when loading FontAwesome 4.7.0

Tags: php, laravel, cors, font-awesome

I get a problem. I already read a lot of reference but still get error.

> Access to font at 'http://192.168.0.1/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

What i have done?

**First Effort**

> I try to make new file .htaccess in /public/font folder.

Inside .htaccess i write :

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

**Second effort**

I try to use Middleware, create new file call CORS.php

Inside CORS.php i write

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode as Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use Log;

class CORS extends Middleware {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        Log::info("CORS 1");

        $origin = $request->header('origin');
        Log::info("Origin in CORS : $origin");
        $origin = $origin ?? '*';

        // ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
        // $headers = [
        //     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => $origin,
        //     'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD, PATCH',
        //     'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Authorization,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Set-Cookie',
        //     'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'=> 'true'
        // ];

        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => $origin,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'GET, POST',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Authorization,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Set-Cookie',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'=> 'true'
        ];

        if($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
            // The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
            return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);

        foreach($headers as $key => $value) {
            $response->header($key, $value);
        }

        Log::info("CORS");
        Log::info($response);
        return $response;
    }

}
```

**Result :**

> First effort and Second Effort still not works. Second effort only
> works for API request (if you add GET and OPTIONS in API).

**My Question :**

> My goal is i want to access fontawesome from other Laravel Server.
> What's my fault?

Comment: You might need to expand your `.htaccess` with `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,OPTIONS,HEAD,PUT,DELETE,PATCH";
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Nonce, DNT, X-CustomHeader";

Comment: @GuidoFaecke : can you give example?

Comment: add `woff2` to the list

Comment: @Amir : sorry still not works. Same error happen.

Comment: The `origin: null` in the error message seems suspect to me. Is there perhaps a redirection involved, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72004541/16462950)? From where do you try to access the font? From a web application or a desktop application?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen : From Web A (Laravel) to Web B (Laravel). Font stored in public/font folder of Web B

Comment: Can you share the client-side code that requests the font?

Comment: How is the `http://192.168.0.1/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0` request translated to a filename in the `/public/font` folder? What becomes of the `?v=4.7.0` parameter?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen : fontaeesome-webfont.woff2.