# CORS error on subsequent request after redirect, Origin header is null

Tags: javascript, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I have a statically hosted website, hosted on **domain-a.com**. This website is accessing an image from the backend, which is hosted on a separate domain (**domain-b.com**), https://domain-b.com/api/logo.jpg. However, the API needs authentication to be accessed so we have to
attach the `Authorization Bearer <the user's token>` via a service-worker script. The service worker script looks like this:

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', async function (event: FetchEvent) {
  // Only modify requests to the API on domain-b.com
  if (!event.request.url.includes('domain-b.com')) return

  // Add the Authentication header to the request
  const newRequest = new Request(event.request, {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer <the user's token>` },
    mode: 'cors',
  })
  event.respondWith(fetch(newRequest))
})
```

This works well if we have an image actually hosted on the backend but this is not the case for us.
The backend validates the authentication and then responds with a 302 redirect to where the file is actually hosted
(our CloudFront on **domain-c.com**).

All is well when sending the request from Postman or curl but when the request is made from the browser, I get a CORS error on the subequent request (the follow up to the redirect).
The problem seems to be that the browser does not send the correct `Origin` header on the second request to domain-c.com. It is present on the first request to domain-b.com but is set to `null` on the second.
This is a problem since CloudFront only sets the CORS headers if `Origin` is set to a value and it matches one of the specified domains in the configuration. The CORS headers are not returned wihout a value
on `Origin` even when it is set to allow all (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`).

I see two possible solutions to this but can't make any of them work:

1. Make the browser send the `Origin` header on the second request
2. Make CloudFront always respond with the CORS headers, even when the Origin is not set or matches.

I have tried configuring CloudFront CORS settings but to no avail. I have tried returning various CORS headers from the API (**domain-b.com**) with the redirect which allows the subsequent preflight to be made to **domain-c.com** but `Origin` is still not set.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What you're observing (an `Origin` header with a `null` value during a cross-origin redirect) is normal browser behaviour. There's nothing you can do to change it. What you should do, if possible, is send the request directly to `domain-c.com`. Whatever you do, never allow the `null` origin in your CORS configuration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: CORS error when API 302 redirects to same domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72002362/react-cors-error-when-api-302-redirects-to-same-domain)

Answer (score 0):

You can try cloudfront function to add origin.

[add-origin-header](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-functions/blob/main/add-origin-header/index.js)