302 Redirect not allowed even though origin header is correct
I have client A (https://something.localtest.me:3002) making a request to backend B (https://something.localtest.me:8000/api/some_path).
Backend B responds with a 302 redirecting to client C (https://localtest.me:3006).
I control the code on all 3 systems.
However Chrome is blocking with the following error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localtest.me:3006/some/path/123?token=blabla' (redirected from 'https://something.localtest.me:8000/api/some_path') from origin 'https://something.localtest.me:3002' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://something.localtest.me:3002' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

In C i set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to equal https://something.localtest.me:3002
Clearly the origin is correct right ? Any idea what I am missing. (note: i also tried making the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in C equal the backend origin https://something.localtest.me:8000 but that also didn't work.
EDIT:
I've made both B and C allow A and it still doesn't work.
In C i have in the next.config.js
async headers() {
  ....
  headers: [
    {key:'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://something.localtest.me:3002'} 
  ]
}

And in B i have
resp = HttpResponse(status=302)
resp['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'https://something.localtest.me:3002'
resp['Location']= https://localtest.me:3006

Getting the exact same error

Both servers (running at https://something.localtest.me:8000 and https://localtest.me:3006) need to be configured for CORS and allow Web origin https://something.localtest.me:3002.

@jub0bs Ive made an edit to show i did that and it still isn't working.

This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72002362/react-cors-error-when-api-302-redirects-to-same-domain: The redirected request is made with Origin: null, not Origin: https://something.localtest.me:3002.
